# How to order by two fields in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have a recordset of partners. Now I want to order this recordset by two attributes. One of this attributes is a simple `Char`, but the other one is a `Many2one`, which is a problem.

Example (suppose variable `partners` is the recordset):

- This works: `partners.sorted(key=lambda r: r.name)` (with `Char` no problem).
- This does not work: `partners.sorted(key=lambda r: r.country_id)` (with `Many2one`, you must add an attribute of the other model).
- This works: `partners.sorted(key=lambda r: r.country_id.id)` (now we have indicated an attribute of `res.country`, the recordset is ordered rightly).

The problem is: I need to order by two fields, as I wrote above. For that it seems that I have to use `itemgetter`, but:

- This does not work: `partners.sorted(key=itemgetter('name', 'country_id'))` (`country_id` is ignored, as when I tried to order by only this one above).
- This gives an error: `partners.sorted(key=itemgetter('name', 'country_id.id'))` (the error message is that `country_id.id` is not a field of `res.partner`).
- This seems to work: `partners.sorted(key=itemgetter('name', 'phone'))` (because both fields are `Char`).

I also tried to link two sorted in a row, this way:

```
partners.sorted(key=lambda r: r.name).sorted(key=lambda r: r.country_id.id)
```

But it is not working neither, because the second `sorted` function messes up the result of the first one.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```py
partners.sorted(key=lambda p: (p.name, p.country_id.id))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to sort using `country name`.
Using your last code line and calling sort one time it will solve the problem:

```
partners.sorted(key=lambda r: (r.name, r.country_id.name))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Kenly, that works, but it is not necessary to order by country `name`, I was able to order by country `id` with no problem.